# TestNG: send dynamic param from Shell script to Java file

Tags: testng, appium

I want to send a dynamic parameter from sh file to my Java. But I can not get this param.

My code like below: I tried to send "filePath" parameter from scripts.sh like below

```
$./scripts.sh "/opt/test.apk"
```

source scripts.sh like below:

```
java -cp libs/*:bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml -filePath $1
```

my testng.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
    <classes>        
      <parameter name="filePath" value="${filePath}"></parameter> 
      <class name="example.FullTestAndroidApp"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
 </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

and in Java class, i tried to get filePath param:

```
public class FullTestAndroidApp {
@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("filePath")
public void initContext(@Optional String filePath) throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("Parameterized value is : " + filePath);

 }
```

output: Parameterized value is : null

So I can not get filePath dynamic params from SH file.

Please help me. What i am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do this

First change your shell script to something like below :

`java -Dfilepath=$1 -cp libs/*:bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

Your modified `testng.xml` would look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <!-- [/opt/test.apk] would be the default value of filePath-->
            <parameter name="filePath" value="/opt/test.apk"/>
            <class name="example.FullTestAndroidApp"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Now change your method to as below

```
@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("filePath")
public void initContext(@Optional String filePath) throws MalformedURLException {
    //We query the JVM property "filepath" and if its not defined then we fall back to the
    //parameter that was sent to us via the suite xml
    System.out.println("Parameterized value is : " + System.getProperty("filepath", filePath));
}
```